# is meminfo an accurate look at free mem?

Tags: linux, memory, vmware

So is meminfo the best way to say there is X free memory? I ask this question because my company states that this is not an accurate way to represent free memory. In fact, it is the sum of memfree, cached, buffers, slab and if on a vmware box, the vmware ballon is added from /proc/vmmemctl. thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the vmware host case, I had a similar problem with one or our servers, see https://serverfault.com/questions/435307/redhat-linux-server-paging-sum-of-res-rss-buffers-cached-total-who-is-u

I think the problem with meminfo is that it doesn't clearly show the memory used by vmmemctl. Since vmmemctl is a driver, the memory it uses doesn't appear also in top/ps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `/proc/meminfo` is accurate (but I can't prove that), and more generally the `/proc` pseudo-file system gives you a lot of information about the system (and each process).

Of course it gives information about the kernel providing it (so the kernel running inside your VMware virtual machine).

If you are concerned by a specific process, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8510694/841108)

Comment: i'm not necessarily looking for a specific process. i'm more interested in understanding why top and the linux community are apparently wrong and my company is right (as they see it).