# Memory pages used by a process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, mmap

I want to get the list of all mapped pages (allocated memory) in a Linux Process at runtime. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From inside the process, on Linux, you can read and parse `/proc/self/maps` ; try `cat /proc/self/maps` which will show you the memory map of the process running that `cat`

From another process, for the map of the process of pid 1234, you can read `/proc/1234/maps`

And there is also `/proc/self/smaps` etc.

The Linux specific [dladdr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr) function is sometimes useful also.

If you are concerned by pages which are really in RAM, use [mincore](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mincore) & [msync](http://linux.die.net/man/2/msync)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/proc/[PID]/maps` for this.

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/$your_pid/maps` and examine other files in `/proc/$your_pid` they may be useful too